# Getting a random position fixed distance from a point

Tags: python, random, simulation

I am trying to develop a solar system simulation.

To initialise the display, I need the planets to be randomly placed in their orbitals (fixed orbital radius) from the Sun. How do I get the random position?

I am using pygame for the display.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I generate random points on a circles circumference in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879258/how-can-i-generate-random-points-on-a-circles-circumference-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if a center of a circle is at (0,0) and radius is R, you can get the coordinates of a point on circumference using the formula
x = R * cos(theta)
y = R * sin(theta)

python code will look like this:

```
import random
import math  

R = 5  
theta = random.uniform(0, 2 * math.pi)   
x = R * math.cos(theta)
y = R * math.sin(theta)
```

Comment: What does random.uniform() do, as compared to maybe randint() or something?